# JOOQ 3.1 Code generate just for tables

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is it posible to run the code generator just for tables?  I can exclude pkgs fine in `<exclude>` because they all end with _pkg but i am still generating functions and types as there is no common part in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ 3.8 has added support for code generation flags to turn on/off specific types of generated artefacts ([#3482](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3482)). The configuration is:

```xml
<database>
    <includePackages>false</includePackages>
    <includeRoutines>false</includeRoutines>
    ...
```

Prior to version 3.8, you can still implement your own `org.jooq.util.Database`, e.g. overriding the `OracleDatabase` from jOOQ-meta, and then produce only `TableDefinition` items, none of the other items:

```java
public class NoRoutinesOracleDatabase extends OracleDatabase {
    @Override
    protected List<RoutineDefinition> getRoutines0() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // other things you want to prevent...
}
```

You can then configure the code generator to use that `Database`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>com.example.NoRoutinesOracleDatabase</name>
            ...
```